# Vapor 4, Schema Truncate

Tags: swift, postgresql, schema, vapor

What is the easiest way to truncate a table on a migration reversion function in vapor 4? Must I write a custom query or is there a method like .delete() than can be called, like .truncate()?

```
func revert(on database: Database) -> EventLoopFuture<Void> {
        return database.schema("legislative_jurisdictions").delete()
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I have so far, that doesn't require any raw sql, is to query the whole table and delete

```
func revert(on database: Database) -> EventLoopFuture<Void> {
        return TableToTruncate.query(on: database).delete().transform(to: ())
    }
```

This empties the table entirely.